# Android : showDialog not displayer inside onActivityResult after take photo

Tags: android, dialog

When i'm in onActivityResult and i try to show a custom progress dialog,
The dialog is not show, but the function is called, but nothing is displayed
If i put this dialog in Oncreate it's working i see the dialogbox,
Is it possible to show a custom dialog on return of Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT / MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Thanks

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  Parseur UploadPhoto = new Parseur();
  showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
  if (requestCode == z_const.REQUEST_INTENT_CODE_PHOTO_CHOISIR) {
   String selectedImagePath;
   Uri selectedImageUri;
   if (data != null){
    selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    Log.e(TAG, "PHOTO CHOISIR " + selectedImagePath+"Res"+resultCode);
    UploadPhoto.uploadPhoto(InfoPasse,selectedImagePath);
   }
  }
  finish();
 }

 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  Log.e(TAG," DIAL appeller "+id);
  switch(id) {
  case PROGRESS_DIALOG:
   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Photo.this);
   progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
   progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
   progressThread = new ProgressThread(handler);
   progressThread.start();
   return progressDialog;
  default:
   return null;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anwser :)

1. Play the loking task in AsyncTask inside doInBackground
2. Start dialog before call intent

So replace the loking task UploadPhoto.uploadPhoto(InfoPasse,selectedImagePath);
by new UploadInBackground().execute(selectedImagePath);
and AsyncTask look like :

```
private class UploadInBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {
@Override
protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
    UploadPhoto.uploadPhoto(InfoPasse,params[0]);
    return null
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    finish();
}
```

}